# Getting MIN date

Tags: sql, t-sql, db2

I have a table(A) that looks something like:

```
ID     Date
1      2012/01/12
2      2012/01/01
3      2012/01/03
4      2012/03/12
```

If I wanted to grab the `MIN` date for this query, would I just `group by`?

```
select
  a.ID,
  MIN(a.DATE),
  b.name,
  c.price
FROM
  tablea a inner join tableb b on a.ID = b.ID
  inner join tablec c b.ID = c.ID
```

Comment: What your query does is grab the minimum date for each `id`, `name`, and `price`. Is that what you want? If not, what *do* you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for those that had the minimum date, then you can do this:

```
select
  a.ID,
  a.DATE,
  b.name,
  c.price
FROM tablea a 
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT Id, MIN(Date) AS MinDate 
   FROM tablea
   GROUP BY Id
) As minA ON a.date = mina.mindate AND a.id = mina.id
inner join tableb b on a.ID = b.ID
inner join tablec c b.ID = c.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a window function. The correct expression is:

```
select a.id,
       min(a.date) over () as mindate,
       b.name, c.price
. . .
```

This says to get the min of the date over the data.  There is no partition, so it gets it over all the data.

Comment: @Nick search for *window functions* `:D`

Comment: @Nick . . . do some research on window functions (also called analytic functions in Oracle).  They are available in most databases (SQL Server, Postgres, DB2, and Oracle for instance) and are part of the ANSI standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH recordList
as
(
    select  a.ID,
            a.DATE,
            b.name,
            c.price,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID
                                ORDER BY a.Date ASC) rn
    FROM    tablea a 
            inner join tableb b on a.ID = b.ID
            inner join tablec c b.ID = c.ID
)
SELECT  ID, DATE, name, Price
FROM    recordList
WHERE   rn = 1
```